# Python - Write a function that takes a string as an argument and displays the letters backward, one per line

Tags: python, traversal, while-loop

This is an exercise from "How to think like a Computer Scientist".  I am learning Python/programming and I'm not sure how to do accomplish this task.

Here is an example in the book that displays the letters forwards, I can't figure out how to get the opposite effect.  Has to use a while-loop.

```
fruit = 'banana'
index = 0
while index > len(fruit):
        letter = fruit[index]
        print letter
        index = index + 1
```

Comment: shouldn't it be `while index < len(fruit):` ?

Comment: Urgh. Another trivial exercise that asks you to do things the wrong way.

Comment: @Ignacio - seriously; iteration needs to be more prevalent. :|

Comment: @Ignacio: No CS101 book is going to teach people to do things in Python-specific ways, nor should they.  You need to learn how to handle loops and variables and conditionals before you even *look* at iterators--and obviously, simply calling `reversed` would teach nothing at all.

Answer (score 5):

Well, it's basically the same thing, but:

1. You have to start from the last letter instead of the first, so instead of `index = 0`, you'll need `index = len(fruit) - 1`
2. You have to *decrease* the index instead of increasing it at the end of the while loop, so `index = index + 1` becomes `index = index - 1`.
3. The condition of the while loop is different; you want to stay within the loop as long as `index` points to a valid character index. Since `index` starts from `len(fruit) - 1` and it gets one smaller after every iteration, eventually it will get smaller than zero. Zero is still a valid character index (it refers to the first character of the string), so you'll want to stay within the loop as long as `index >= 0` -- this will be the `while` condition.

Putting it all together:

```
fruit = 'banana'
index = len(fruit) - 1
while index >= 0:
    letter = fruit[index]
    print letter
    index = index - 1
```

Answer (score 2):

i think that the simplest way is

```
print ''.join(reversed('banana'))
```

or, if you want one letter per line

```
print '\n'.join(reversed('banana'))
```

i think it's better because join is the standard way to operate on strings, so...

Answer (score 1):

Simplest as:

```
>>> def print_reversed(s):
...   for letter in reversed(s):
...     print letter,
... 
>>> print_reversed('banana')
a n a n a b
>>>
```

Other possible solution could be putting the index to be the last index of the string. Then you are going to read the string letter by letter backwards, lowering the index value by 1 each time. Then the code snipplet that you showed could become:

```
>>> def print_reversed2(s):
...   index = len(s) - 1
...   while index >= 0:
...     letter = fruit[index]
...     print letter
...     index = index - 1
... 
>>> print_reversed2('banana')
a
n
a
n
a
b
>>>
```

Using the interactive interpreter (just type 'python' in a command prompt) could help you experiment with such code snipplets. Like for example:

```
>>> fruit = 'banana'
>>> len(fruit)
6
>>> len(fruit) - 1
5
>>> while index >= 0:
...   print "index at: " + str(index)
...   print "fruit[index] at: " + fruit[index]
...   index = index - 1
... 
index at: 5
fruit[index] at: a
index at: 4
fruit[index] at: n
index at: 3
fruit[index] at: a
index at: 2
fruit[index] at: n
index at: 1
fruit[index] at: a
index at: 0
fruit[index] at: b
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

This may helping receive any word and return its reversed le

```
 word = input("please enter word")
 letter = word[len(word)-1]
 index = len(word)-1
 while index >= 0:
     letter = word[index]
     print(letter)
     index = index - 1
```